# Multiple and similars forms - Webform or Content type

Tags: 7, nodes, webforms

I am working on a project that require a lot of similar forms. I had the idea of creating a content type per form, but with only 2 content types for this forms I am close to 100 fields already and I am concern with performance and scalability.

The site runing Drupal 7 will have users that will fill this forms and since they are content type the permissions are easy to apply to allow the user to only see, edit and/or delete their own content. I started to think that maybe the webform module was better for this task as I will have a lot of forms, but that I will see them as nodes with the form attach to it.

My questions is:

Will the module webform allow the users to only see their content and have access over it (CRUD)?

Any other suggestion on how to accomplish this task is always appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I get it right. What about a content type with a field that is an array of fields. You would then generate a desired form using php code. Is that a direction you are looking for?

Comment: I can see your point, but I want to have some sort of UI for the user to keep adding fields to the form without having to touch the PHP code.

Comment: So you want to allow user, to define his own content types that others will be able to use? Theoretically it should be possible to restrict (based on a role) the standard forms for "add content" and "add content type". I am brain-storming here...

Comment: Can the data collected thru a webform be limited to the user that enter it?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want users to be able to do? Do they create the forms themselves? Do they fill out their own forms? Each other's forms? Regardless, it sounds to me like webform would be a neat fit - webforms are normal nodes so you can use normal node access modules if core permissions aren't sufficient (or use [`hook_node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) to do it programatically).

Comment: @Andy - In a nutshell any user of the site can fill any of the available forms, but the user can not see what other user has submitted. One of my concerns is that I don't want to end up with a database of 1000's of tables and records all over the place.

Comment: IIRC there's a specific permission for that in webform - _view own submission_ or something.

Comment: @Andy the user can view, edit and/or delete his/her own submission.

Comment: So that means your problem's solved no?! (Sorry, think I'm missing something!)